# Pandas date_range to generate monthly data at beginning of the month

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I'm trying to generate a date range of monthly data where the day is always at the beginning of the month:

```
pd.date_range(start='1/1/1980', end='11/1/1991', freq='M')
```

This generates `1/31/1980`, `2/29/1980`, and so on. Instead, I just want `1/1/1980`, `2/1/1980`,...

I've seen other question ask about generating data that is always on a specific day of the month, with answers saying it wasn't possible, but beginning of month surely must be possible!

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You can do this by changing the `freq` argument from `'M'` to `'MS'`:

```
d = pandas.date_range(start='1/1/1980', end='11/1/1990', freq='MS')    
print(d)
```

This should now print:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1980-01-01', '1980-02-01', '1980-03-01', '1980-04-01',
               '1980-05-01', '1980-06-01', '1980-07-01', '1980-08-01',
               '1980-09-01', '1980-10-01', 
               ...
               '1990-02-01', '1990-03-01', '1990-04-01', '1990-05-01',
               '1990-06-01', '1990-07-01', '1990-08-01', '1990-09-01',
               '1990-10-01', '1990-11-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=131, freq='MS', tz=None)
```

Look into the [*offset aliases*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) part of the documentation. There it states that `'M'` is for the end of the month (month end frequency) while `'MS'` for the beginning (month start frequency).

Answer (score 14):

It is worth noting that `pandas.date_range()` only includes dates **within** the defined interval, which may not be expected :

```
start = "2020-03-08"
end = "2021-03-08"
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='MS')
```

results in

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-04-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01',
           '2020-08-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-11-01',
           '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

For `MS`, a workaround to include the first day of the opening month is to work only with the year and month of the start date :

```
pd.date_range(start[:7], end, freq='MS')
```

will then give

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01',
           '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01',
           '2020-11-01', '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01',
           '2021-03-01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

If you wish to keep the same starting day for each month, you can then add the offset with `pd.DateOffset()` :

```
pd.date_range(start[:7], end, freq='MS') + pd.DateOffset(days=7)
```

will give

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-08', '2020-04-08', '2020-05-08', '2020-06-08',
           '2020-07-08', '2020-08-08', '2020-09-08', '2020-10-08',
           '2020-11-08', '2020-12-08', '2021-01-08', '2021-02-08',
           '2021-03-08'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

As mentioned in comments, note that trouble may come with this workaround for offsets higher or equals to 28.

Comment: This causes trouble if the desired date is on 29th and feb has 28 days.

Comment: @anishtain4 Right (for the last part, adding an offset).  Actually trouble with this method comes for any offset equals to or higher than 28.

Comment: `'MS'` for `date_range` does *not* "makes the range start at the beginning of the next month". But it does include only date points *inside* the range defined by `start` and `end`. If the `start` is a date point in the freq supplied, `date_range` *will* return that date point in the result.

Comment: @pablete This was poorly worded indeed.  Answer updated, thanks for the comment.