# Month label in plot is out of sequence

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I am plotting a monthly timeseries out of the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 


df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2001-01-01 00:00',end = '2001-12-31 23:59',freq='M'),
                  'value': np.array([1.63240641, 0.71793968, 0.15350684, 2.14915722, 0.45236403,
                                     0.48638794, 0.74329402, 0.38316468, 0.96695818, 0.80566539,
                                     1.23177184,0.556])})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d',errors ='coerce') 
df.set_index('Date',inplace = True)
df.drop(columns = 'date', axis = 1,inplace = True)
```

with the following code snippet:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.index, df.value, color = 'tab:red', ls = '-.', marker = 'p')

# Major ticks every month.
# Set the locator
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month

# Specify the format - %b gives us Jan, Feb...
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
# Specify formatter
X.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

Which gave me the plot: [image]

But, if you notice the labeling in X axis starts from *Feb* instead of *Jan*. `Feb` is displaying value of `Jan`.
I have crosschecked my code many time but no luck yet.

Can anybody help me out on this issue.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know pandas plot works fine here but for my specific purpose I need to plot it with matplotlib.

Comment: print `pd.date_range('2001-01-01 00:00',end = '2001-12-31 23:59',freq='M')` and have a look at the dates you're getting

Comment: I'm guessing you want `freq="MS"` instead

Comment: Tried your suggestion and works well. Thanks a lot @ Riley

Comment: [Pandas date_range to generate monthly data at beginning of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915828/pandas-date-range-to-generate-monthly-data-at-beginning-of-the-month)