# Inclusive argument is not working as expected in pd.date_range()

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

With `pandas 1.40` it was introduced the argument `inclusive` in the class `pd.date_range()`.
Reading the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

> inclusive{“both”, “neither”, “left”, “right”}, default “both”
> Include boundaries; Whether to set each bound as closed or open

I wanted to use it to create a `df` with monthly frequency starting on the first day of 01/2020 and finishing on the first day of the month of 12/2022.
I wrote this code:

```
df = pd.date_range(start='01/01/2020', end='31/12/2022', freq = "M", inclusive = "left")
```

Which is not giving my expected output.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-30',
           '2020-05-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-31',
           '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31',
           '2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-30',
           '2021-05-31', '2021-06-30', '2021-07-31', '2021-08-31',
           '2021-09-30', '2021-10-31', '2021-11-30', '2021-12-31',
           '2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30',
           '2022-05-31', '2022-06-30', '2022-07-31', '2022-08-31',
           '2022-09-30', '2022-10-31', '2022-11-30'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

**Expected Output**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01',
           '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01',
           '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-01',
           '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01',
           '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01',
           '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01',
           '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
           '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01',
           '2022-09-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-12-01' ],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

1. How do I get my expected output with `pd.date_range()`?
2. What I misunderstood on how to use correctly the argument `inclusive` inside `pd.date_range()`?

Comment: I will not be able to explain the whole answer but frequency "MS"(month start frequency) is what you need to specify in freq. Check [Offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) for more detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas date\_range to generate monthly data at beginning of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915828/pandas-date-range-to-generate-monthly-data-at-beginning-of-the-month)

Comment: @imxitiz yes thank you! I searched before but it was not enough

Comment: @imxitiz while i fixed one issue i would also understand better how inclusive works and if is just because i didn't defined `MS` as is something introduced recently with pandas 1.4.0 but probably is a not specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from @imxitiz [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75176014/inclusive-argument-is-not-working-as-expected-in-pd-date-range?noredirect=1#comment132658375_75176014), try

```py
pd.date_range(start='01/01/2020', end='31/12/2022', freq = "MS", inclusive = "left")
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01',
               '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01',
               '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-01',
               '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01',
               '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01',
               '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01',
               '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
               '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01',
               '2022-09-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have pandas version 1.1.5 Inclusive is not recognized and generates an exception like this :

```
*builtins.TypeError: _generate_range() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inclusive'*
```

What you want has nothing to do with `inclusive` but to frequency type :

- **M** for month end
- **MS** for month beginning (S is for Start)

All types defined here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases

**Proposed command line**

```py
df = pd.date_range(start='01/01/2020', end='31/12/2022', freq = "MS")
```

**Result**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-04-01',
               '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01',
               '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-01',
               '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01',
               '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01',
               '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01',
               '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
               '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01',
               '2022-09-01', '2022-10-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```